# Generate form start tag with Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

When I want to split my form in twig, I use `form_widget` of `form_row`, but I have to write the form tag manually

```
<form action='path("form_action_path")' method='...'>
```

Is there a function in twig that allow me to generate this tag automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Symfony 2.3, there is a [`form_start`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-start-view-variables) function:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
```